# Android accessing parent class values after starting an intent?

Tags: android

I'm starting an intent in an activity class TTWifi.java as follows

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SocketClient.class);

startActivity(i);
```

Now how do i access the variables of `TTWifi.class` from `SocketClient.class`?

I believe there is a way to send values between them. I am very new to android, guess this is a very fundamental stuff :) Would really appreciate if someone can help me out in this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through this following code we can share the values to activities

```
Intent i=new Intent(FitnessGraph.this,Nami.class).putExtra("<StringName>"," String Value");
```

Use above code in parent activity
and by using below line we can retrieve that value in child activity.Write this line in child activity

```
String s= getIntent().getStringExtra("<StringName>");
```

Comment: One more doubt, how do i access the instance of the parentClass (TTWifi.java) ??

Comment: Try TTWiffi <instance Name>=new TTWiffi(); in child activity

Comment: by doing this... we will be getting a new object right... i need control of the first activity.. how can i get that done?